# Half of the input border is darker

Tags: html, css

Simple question, why half of the input border is darker? When I set red it look like a gradient from light red to dark red, with gray it is from gray to black.

```
add-form {
    @include flex-center;
    

    &__input {
        margin: 2rem 0 0 2rem;
        padding: 2rem 1rem 2rem 1rem;
        font-size: 1.4rem;
        border-radius: 10rem;
        border-color: red;
    }
```

HTML

```
<form class="add-form" name="add" method="POST"> {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form }} <!-- it has class add-form__input it is from Django widget.-->
                <button  name="add" class="add-form__submit-button" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </form>
```

Comment: There would be another CSS getting applied. The style you have provided doesn't have any sort of gradient properties in it. To check which styling is applied for the input, use browser's "inspect element".

Comment: In this code there is nothing to show non-red border.

Comment: Yeah I checked elements and I still have no idea why 50% of border is darker.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 3):

Somehow I figured out.

```
 &__input {
        margin: 2rem 0 0 2rem;
        padding: 2rem 1rem 2rem 1rem;
        font-size: 1.4rem;
        border-style: solid;
        border: 2px, gray;
        border-radius: 2rem;
}
```

I had to add border 2px and border style.

Answer (score 3):

The default button border is the bottom half is black and a thicker line than the top half. If you want to get rid of this, you can instead try this:

```
border: 2px solid red;
```